# I'm using TextMate at the moment, any reason for moving to Coda or MacVim?

Tags: editor, textmate, macvim, coda

I'm using **TextMate** at the moment as editor and it seems to be good for many tasks. **Coda** and **MacVim** are quite popular as well, so I was just wondering if there are any reasons/advantages to use those Editors instead of TextMate.

Other solutions are accepted as well.

Comment: Try Coda, you will fell in love with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no advantage, pure personal preference, I've just started using Coda, having moved from using Smultron. Coda is great for web dev/design (not really done much software programming, just PHP, jQuery etc)

Answer (score 2):

I moved from TextMate to MacVim. My -- entirely personal and subjective -- reason for switching was the breadth of available documentation, plugins, hacks, tutorials, etc. for Vim. It made it easier for me to research ways to quickly perform common tasks.

Another turning point for me was the realization that the entire TextMate project hinges upon how much or little attention it gets from its author. Case in point: a while back an update was released that broke a feature I use quite often. The problem was rectified within a couple of weeks, but I didn't like the feeling that my hands were tied while I waited for the developer to fix it.

Also, once I grokked Vim's motion commands, I didn't really want to use anything else for writing text.

Comment: MacVim also. I was curious about it and profited from a slow week at my job to dive into Vim. Now I'm hooked. I haven't touched TextMate in the last two months except to find the right label of a menu item for an answer here or on superuser. Also I found Coda and Espresso to be totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used TextMate, but I abhor Coda for anything but simple HTML or CSS. It's shocking for anything with actual programming (jump to function definition? Code folding? What's that?)

Comment: I should probably note that I am not a regular Mac user, but I used Coda for a month at a job I did recently. I must say the Home/End keys not doing what I was used to, annoyed me more than anything - I'm not sure if that was a Mac or a Coda thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not to start another editor flame war, but why not Emacs? I use textMate sometimes still, but Emacs runs across all platforms. I use it for R with ESS, Python, and LaTeX.

edit- i should add I'am unfamiliar with Coda. Whatever works best for you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been a long user of Coda, simply because when I was getting started with web development, Coda was immensely popular and repeatedly mentioned. I've never looked elsewhere because Coda hit the right balance between functionality and ease of use/unclutteredness. However, recently, Coda's lack of decent support for HAML and my inability to add that support by writing a plugin forced me to look elsewhere. While I'm yet to try out TextMate, for pure web development, not just a text editor, I would recommend Espresso. It's got a much better editor than Coda, even including Karpie's beloved code folding.